# Use a same JQuery function for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I am currently learning web development using Flask. I am stuck at a place where I want to use a jquery function to return the value from an input tag in for that corresponding row.

Here;s my HTML:

```html
enter code here
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %} Menu item {% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped table-inverse table-responsive">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <form>
          {% for item in menu_category %}
          <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{item.item_Name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.item_Price}}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control test" name="item_id{{ loop.index0 }}" id="itemID" placeholder="" value="{{ item.item_Id }}">
              <a name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary clsAddToCart" href="#" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </form>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p id=result>cart: </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's my Jquery function:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.clsAddToCart').bind('click', function() {
          $.getJSON('{{ url_for("func_add_to_cart") }}', {
            productID: $("input[name^='item_id']").val(),
        }, function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data.result);
        });
        return false;
        });
        });
   </script>
```

I just want the function to return the corresponding item id on the button click, but somehow it always returns the first item id only for all.

Much Thanks!

Comment: Don’t try to assign unique ids to each tag.  You can get a reference to the clicked element in your handler either by `this` or by `event.target`, and you know that the input field you want is always the `previousElementSibling` (or whatever jQuery equivalent) of the clicked element,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hope you like it here. Given that this is a client-side question providing actual HTML - harvested from the browser - can be very helpful in understanding and answering your question. Not need to post server-side code if it does not clarify your question. **Otherwise we become the web server and we have to process the server-side code in order to address your question. Please take the Tour: stackoverflow.com/tour and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/) for the `val` method explains this on the very first line:

> Get the current value of the *first* element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

(the emphasis is mine to show the relevant part for your question).

For each "add to cart" button to work on the corresponding input, you can use `$(this)` to get hold of the specific button clicked on, and then use, for example, the [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method (since in your HTML the input is the immediately preceding sibling - there are slightly more sophisticated things you could do to make this more robust to changes in your HTML, but I'll let you figure those out if you need them):

```
$(function() {
  $('.clsAddToCart').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('{{ url_for("func_add_to_cart") }}', {
      productID: $(this).prev().val(),
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data.result);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, This worked!. I am still a newbie, got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all input elements the same id ('itemID'). Should be like: 'item{{ item.item_Id }}'. May be this can solve your problem.

Your jQuery function should be like :

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.clsAddToCart').bind('click', function() {
          $.getJSON('{{ url_for("func_add_to_cart") }}', {
            productID: $(this).closest('input').val(), //<==
        }, function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data.result);
        });
        return false;
        });
        });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the correct `input` element you have to make use of the context of the click event. The `this` keyword refers to the element that was click. Therefore you can use that to target the correct `input` element using relative positioning to `this`. Per your structure any of the following should be fine as a replacement for `$("input[name^='item_id']").val()`:

```
$(this).siblings().val(); //OR
$(this).closest('td').find('input').val(); //OR
$(this).parent().children('input').val(); //AND SO ON AND SO FORTH
```

Please remember that:

1. `.bind()` is deprecated as of v3, so use `.on()`
2. Keep all your id attributes unique and, no need to have them if you don't need them.

```js
    $(function() {
        $('.clsAddToCart').on('click', function() {
            console.log( $(this).siblings().val() );
          /*$.getJSON('{{ url_for("func_add_to_cart") }}', {
            productID: $("input[name^='item_id']").val(),
        }, function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data.result);
        });
        return false;*/
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped table-inverse table-responsive">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <form>
          <!--{% for item in menu_category %}-->
          <tr>
            <td scope="row">Item Name 1</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control test" name="item_id-1" id="itemID1" placeholder="" value="id1">
              <a name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary clsAddToCart" href="#" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td scope="row">Item Name 2</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control test" name="item_id-1" id="itemID2" placeholder="" value="id2">
              <a name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary clsAddToCart" href="#" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td scope="row">Item Name 3</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control test" name="item_id-1" id="itemID3" placeholder="" value="id3">
              <a name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary clsAddToCart" href="#" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td scope="row">Item Name 4</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control test" name="item_id-1" id="itemID4" placeholder="" value="id4">
              <a name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary clsAddToCart" href="#" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!--{% endfor %}-->
        </form>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p id=result>cart: </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I did replace the bind() with on(). Much appreciated!

Comment: Very well @Aditya, glad you found a solution that works. Now that you have selected the right answer, feel free to upvote *all* answers that you find useful.